# Why does data manipulation in selection result in reduction of size of query result set?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I was running a query on my Postgresql database version 9.6.
I was selecting urls from a table image_urls having 200 urls with query:

`select url from image_urls limit 10;`

This query was returning the correct output with 10 urls.
However, i wanted to select image urls having http urls instead of https urls.
So, i tried to match the urls with a regex and checked the dimension of text array returned by regex matches with the help of query:

`select array_length(regexp_matches(url, '^http(?!s)', 'g'), 1) from image_urls limit 10;`

The above query was returning 0 results.

I was not able to understand how manipulation in selection of a column in resulting data set reduce the size of the data set ie. atleast 10 rows should have returned with whatever be the result. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least one match, the result of regexp_matches is array:

```
t=# select regexp_matches(tablename, '^pg(?!s)', 'g') from pg_tables limit 1;
 regexp_matches
----------------
 {pg}
(1 row)
```

if you have no matches - [the result is not empty array, but no rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> the function can return no rows, one row, or multiple rows (see the g
>   flag below)

```
t=# select regexp_matches(tablename, '^http(?!s)', 'g') from pg_tables;
 regexp_matches
----------------
(0 rows)
```

and lastly array_length on no rows gives no rows:

```
t=# with no_rows_returned as (select ARRAY[1,2] aa from pg_tables where false)
select array_length(aa,1) from no_rows_returned;
 array_length
--------------
(0 rows)
```

And this behaviour is not exceptional, another example with no rows without `WHERE` clause:

```
t=# select json_agg(tablename) filter (where tablename = 'no such table') from pg_tables;
 json_agg
----------

(1 row)
```

or

```
t=# select unnest(array_remove(array_remove(ARRAY[1,2],1),2));
 unnest
--------
(0 rows)
```